# Writing cucumber features/scenarios on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, mobile, cucumber, syntax-highlighting, gherkin

When at home, I use TextMate 2, and the Gherkin syntax highlighting really makes a difference for me.

But I'd like to write features at the beach, on my iPhone.  I could always open up a text document, but I'm wondering if anyone else had that same desire and created a solution?

Again, my key feature is Gherkin syntax highlighting.

Thanks!

Comment: You're basically asking to develop software using an iPhone. It sounds totally unproductive and you should probably either enjoy the beach or use a computer and work.

Comment: You seriously want to write Gherkin scenarios on an iphone on a beach? Interesting scenario ;) No I haven't had the same desire!